# Pass object as param into Angular ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parameters, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to pass an object as one of the parameters to my ui-router state:

JS:

```
.state('graph', {
  name: 'Graph',
  url: "/graph?{friends}&{start}&{end}",
  templateUrl: 'templates/graphs.html',
  controller: 'GraphController'
})
```

HTML:

```
<a ui-sref="graph({friends: test.friends, start: test.start_date, end: test.end_date})">
  My Graphs
</a>
```

TEST:

```
{
  friends: {
    'friend1': [MORE_DATA],
    'friend2': [MORE_DATA]
  },
  start_date: "Jun-17",
  end_date: "Jun-19"
}
```

However, when I try to access `$stateParams` in the controller, it prints out the string `"[object Object]"`. How can I get the `test.friends` object to be passed through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass objects on the querystring so the way you have constructed the URL for your `graph` state is causing the object to be converted to a string which you are seeing as `[object Object]`.

What you should do instead is create `params` for your state as shown below. This will allow you to pass the object and have it accessible in your controller via `$stateParams`.

```js
angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
    $stateProvider
      .state('main', {
        url: '/',
        template: '<div><a ui-sref="graph({friends: main.friends, start: main.start_date, end: main.end_date})">Go to graph</a></div>',
        controller: 'MainController as main'
      })
      .state('graph', {
        url: '/graph',
        template: '<div>Graph</div><div>{{graph.friends}}</div><div>Start: {{graph.startDate}}, End: {{graph.endDate}}',
        controller: 'GraphController as graph',
        params: {
          friends: null,
          start: null,
          end: null
        }
      });
  })
  .controller('MainController', function() {
    var _this = this;
    _this.friends =
      {
        'friend1': 'friend 1', 
        'friend2': 'friend 2'
      };
    _this.start_date = "Jun-17"; 
    _this.end_date = "Jun-19";
  })
  .controller('GraphController', function($stateParams) {
    var _this = this;
    _this.friends = $stateParams.friends;
    _this.startDate = $stateParams.start;
    _this.endDate = $stateParams.end;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.3/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```